# Chrome Extension (Content Script) Caching CSS

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, caching, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing an extremely simple extension which applies some CSS to facebook's root, i.e: http://www.facebook.com/ only. When the user navigates to another page the CSS should **not** be applied, however it appears that the file is cached and applies to all other pages until a full refresh (F5, etc) is pressed, rendering the extension useless.

Would there be a simple solution to prevent caching for a particular page - or - some javascript to run such as window.reload? This may be a facebook particular issue.

Comment: Please include your `manifest.json` and/or whatever other code you're using to apply the CSS.

Comment: This is probably because facebook doesn't actually reload the full page when navigating, so the already injected css doesn't get removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Chrome extension never cache css. Actually, Facebook use Ajax call to update its content. So most of the time you are on the same page with a different content.

The best way to have a local change is to use javascript script with "document_end" injection. You can use DOM events to detect changes.

Comment: You're correct. Will have to add a tiny amount of complexity to the code.